# What is the difference between pattern required in gsub and gregexpr?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to extract the "source" from this type of sample

```
sample : { "_id" : { "$oid" : "53b16540f4f0687e95da8843" }, "text" : "FCH urge a la FIFA el uso de tecnologÃ­a en decisiones:  2-1 fuel marcador final entre Holanda y MÃ©xico, que si... http://t.co/wiyp8AIxBO", "created_at" : 1404114920, "geo" : null, "source" : "twitterfeed" }
```

Its a continuous Json feed with millions of such samples in continuous text, I used fromJSON (jsonlite package) to import data.

```
pat<-".*?\"source\":\"(.*?).*?\""
l<-regexpr(pattern=pat,text=df$source)
regmatches(df$source,l)

[1] "twitterfeed\"}{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"53b16540f4f0687e95da8844\"},\"text\":\"RT @fifaworldcup_es: #Brasil2014 | Â¡Oct............**(complete text)**
```

I also tried gregexpr but it also print the complete text with my search result at end of each line.

```
pat<-".*?\"source\":\"(.*?).*?\""
poo<-gsub(pat,"\\1",df$source)
poo
[1] "Twitter for AndroidIFTTTTwitter for iPhonetwitterfeedTwitter for iPhoneTwitter for AndroidTwitter Web ClientTwitter for AndroidTwitter for iPhone...**(correct answers)**
```

But i cannot separate this results, I tried gsubfn package

```
poo<-strapplyc(df$source,pat,simplify=rbind)
poo

 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 ""    ""    ""    ""
```

Please tell me why regmatches is not behaving as same as gsub for same pattern & strapplyc cannot detect that pattern but gsub can.

Comment: I put that just to explain thats how it goes into R (formatting), I didn't put it in my code obviosly